# weird gap when using uiscrollview and uilabel

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

here is the problem i have a tow muti-line label with many content, so I use a scroll view to show them all

then I follow this to do the autolayout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW2

basic idea is to make a container view outside the scroll view to make sure the labels can fill the scroll view no matter what direction it is.

here is the hierarchy and constraint:
[image]

and the portrait mode works well:
[image]

**but when it change to landscape mode some wired gap pops up!**
[image]

and the more text i put in the label the higher gap i got!
my question is what should i do to kill those gap?
please give me some explicit solution or just give me an example, thank you!

and i am using autolayout in ios7, so some solution without coding are preferred!